# Getting a namespace not found error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, helper

I have written an XMLHelper as its own project within the application. After adding the 'XMLHelper' Namespace to web.config  i get the following error:

```
The type or namespace name 'XMLHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

At this line in web.config:

```
<add namespace="XMLHelper" />
```

Here are the Using's in XMLUtil Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

namespace XMLHelper
{
    public static class XMLUtil
    {
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: are you using any `namespace` in your code..? can you show what the class header looks like..? as well as the `using` portion at the top of the class..? it would also help to see the .config file as well

Comment: @DJKRAZE updated my question above with the usings

Comment: 2 questions 
1. where are you getting the error is it in this class or a different one..
2nd. when you added this class did you check the properties of the project's namespace to make sure it's the same ?

Comment: @DJKRAZE Getting the error in the web.config at the using line.
the Assembly Name for this project is XMLHelper and the Default Namespace is XMLHelper as well. The Class name is XMLUtil, could that be the cause?

Comment: can't tell unless I see what the config file looks like also is the helper class a dll or a .cs file..? if it's a .dll then add the reference as well to your references by right clicking on references--> select add new reference

Comment: @DJKRAZE Its a .cs file and the Build Action property is set to Compile